# In this sentence, should I use "is" or "are"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Being able to speak and write foreign language are/is the key skill(s) for international students to study abroad.

In this case, should I use plural or not?

Answer (score 1):

Since speaking and writing are two different and therefore seperate skills, I would say:

> Being able to speak and write a foreign language are the key skills for international students to study abroad.

Comment: Thanks. But from your answer, I guess, in some cases, even there is an "and" in the subject, we should still use "is"? Is it possible?

Comment: @deathlee - Peanut butter and jelly **is** my favorite kind of sandwich.

Comment: Note the sentence is really "being able (to speak and write) a foreign language" not "(being able to speak) and (write a foreign language)"; at least, that's more likely what is meant